# Power BI DAX scenario for a complex logic with multiple sub category

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax, business-intelligence, daxstudio

I am stuck in one of the scenario for powerbi.

Below is the dummy data, I want to consider product with latest state in the count against respective subcategory.

E.g. product PRD1 has latest state followup i.e. 5 against sub category xyz so that should be consider under Subcategory xyx only.

Also product PRD5 has latest state ongoing i.e. 3 against sub category "abc" and "xyz" so it should be consider in count against both the sub categories.

Can anyone please suggest any idea how can I handle this situation. Since I tried numerous approach to handle logic but nothing is working as I expected

[image]

```
Category SubCategory Product State   CalcColumn
CAT         abc       PRD1   ongoing     3
CAT         xyz       PRD1   started     2
CAT         xyz       PRD1   ongoing     3
CAT         xyz       PRD1   finished    4
CAT         xyz       PRD1   followup    5
CAT         abc       PRD2   ongoing     3
CAT         xyz       PRD2   started     2
CAT         xyz       PRD2   ongoing     3
CAT         xyz       PRD2   finished    4
CAT         xyz       PRD2   followup    5
CAT         xyz       PRD3   started     2
CAT         xyz       PRD3   ongoing     3
CAT         xyz       PRD3   finished    4
CAT         xyz       PRD3   followup    5
CAT         pqr       PRD4   finished    4
CAT         abc       PRD5   ongoing     3
CAT         xyz       PRD5   ongoing     3
CAT         xyz       PRD6   waiting     1
CAT         xyz       PRD6   started     2
```

Expected output

```
Category Subcategory ProductCount
CAT         abc           5
CAT         xyz           1
CAT         pqr           1
```

Please note that we have slicers for category and subcategory. If we select any particular value under sub category the count will be change as per filter selection

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should `CalcColumn` against PRD5 / ongoing be `4`? If not, it means you don't have a column that you can order against so there is no way to tell which of those PRD5 is the "last row". You have to have some data that orders it.

Comment: We have 5 state waiting, started, on going, finish, follow up. We created a calculated column which will give number like waiting = 1 , started = 2, ongoing = 3, finished =4, follow up =5

Ideally latest state meaning record with maximum value under calculated column.

We can partition by Product and order by calc column in descending

Comment: I know how to do this in SQL but DAX is tricker. In SQL you first find a list of Product and max CalcColumn then you join back to the original table and filter it. Or you just use windowing functions.

Comment: You could easily filter the table in the Query Editor.

Comment: I need inside DAX since we have filter available on visual if I handle on Power Query it won't work properly

Comment: Paste text instead of pictures and please show your expected output.

Comment: I tried to paste the table text in chat, since there is limitation of word in comment i.e. I included detail in the Question description.

Comment: As you should have. Editing your question to add the text is much preferred. It is almost useless to add text data in the comments section

Comment: In your results, how do you a count of `5` for `abc`?  Your data only shows three items total with that subcategory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
-- get the maximum CalcColumn value for each product
VAR t =
    CALCULATETABLE(
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            VALUES('MyTable'[Product])
            ,"CalcColumn",CALCULATE(MAX('MyTable'[CalcColumn]))
        )
        -- you can play with keepfilters, or All(), or remove Calculatetable() to adjust the result you want
       ,ALL('MyTable')
   )
RETURN 
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS('MyTable')
        ,TreatAS(t,'MyTable'[Product],'MyTable'[CalcColumn])
    )
```